# Django REST Framework - NoReverseMatch when using reverse()

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I've been trying to return some URLs using the reverse() function, but no matter what, I get a NoReverseMatch exception:

```
Reverse for 'folder' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

For the sake of troubleshooting, I created some dumbed-down code, but it STILL won't work. Here's my view:

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.reverse import reverse
from rest_framework.views import APIView

class Folder(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        return Response({'url': reverse('folder', request=request)})
```

Here's my URL pattern:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns
from music import views

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns([
    url(r'^folder/$', views.Folder.as_view(), name='folder')])
```

Comment: Have you tried using `django.core.urlresolvers.reverse`?

Comment: @Gocht Yes, but it produces the exact same error. I've also tried reverse_lazy(), but no luck there either.

Comment: Just to check, that url patterns is that inside your music module? If so has that music module's URL's been `included` in the project main `urls.py`? I've been bitten by that a couple times in the past...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You shouldn't pass the request:

```
{'url': reverse('folder')}
```

or

```
{'url': reverse('appname:folder')}
```

if you are using [namespaced URLs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces)

Comment: Thanks! Adding the namespace worked. I still had to pass the request in order to get a fully qualified URL, but I think that's something specific to the REST framework.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue dealing with reverse() Django-Rest-Framework when trying to get reverse for a model in serializers.py

```
    ....

    def get_links(self, obj):
        request = self.context['request']
        return {
            'self': reverse('sprint-detail',
                kwargs={'pk': obj.pk}, request=request),
        }
```

adding the app to the reverse solved it `my_app`

```
    ....

    def get_links(self, obj):
        request = self.context['request']
        return {
            'self': reverse('my_app:sprint-detail',
                kwargs={'pk': obj.pk}, request=request),
        }
```